# Characterization of turning points for the Ramanujan's zeta function in the spirit of a definition by Arias de Reyna and van de Lune

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions, dirichlet-series

In [1] the authors provided a definition and characterization of *turning points* for the Riemann's zeta function. In this post I denote the Ramanujan's zeta function as $$\varphi(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\tau(n)}{n^s},$$
where $s$ denotes the complex variable and $\tau(n)$ is the tau function (this function $\varphi(s)$ has an analytic continuation, functional equation, Euler product, and similar properties than the Riemann's zeta function, see the Wolfram MathWorld encyclopedia *Tau Dirichlet Series* and [2]).

**Motivation.** I tried to write a characterization of those points $b=\sigma+it$ such that $\Im \varphi(b)=0$ and $\Re\varphi'(b)=0$, compare with the definition that the authors of [1] provided in the section *9. Bound for the real loops*. I wrote a similar statement that is showed in my post as **Conjecture.** But I don't know how to determine the corresponding number $A$, and elaborate more the statement of this conjecture in the spirit of the lemma that provided the authors as a characterization of turning points in the mentioned section of [1] and that I evoke as the following **Conjecture**.

**Conjecture.** *The point* $\sigma+it$ *with* $\sigma>A$ (I don't know how to set a suitable $A$, I believe that at least is required $A>7$) *is a turning point for the function* $\varphi(s)$ *if and only if* 
$$\Im\left(\sum_p\log\left(1-\frac{\tau(p)}{p^s}+\frac{p^{11}}{p^{2s}}\right)\right)=0\tag{1}$$
*and* 
$$\Re\left(\sum_p\frac{(\tau(p)p^s-2p^{11})\log p}{p^{2s}+p^{11}-\tau(p)p^s}\right)=0.\tag{2}$$

> **Question.** A) I would like to know if it possible to elaborate more the expressions $(1)$ and $(2)$ to get a chatacterization of the turning points for the Ramanujan's zeta function $\varphi(s)$ with a better mathematical content* than my expressions $(1)$ and $(2)$. Is it possible to determine or approximate the real number $A$? B) Alternatively, express the turning points of $\varphi(s)$ in other interesting way if you are able. **Many thanks.**

*That is, if it is posible to improve my expressions $(1)$ or $(2)$ in the spirit of the work that did the authors of [1].

If in the course of your research you've calculated a turning point for $\varphi(s)$ feel free to add it as example.

### References:

[1] J. Arias de Reyna  and  J. van de Lune, *Some bounds and limits in the theory of Riemann's zeta function*, J. Math. Anal. Appl. 396 (2012) 199-214.

[2] G. H. Hardy, *Ramanujan: Twelve lectures on subjects suggested by his life and work*, AMS Chelsea Publishing (2002).

Comment: I know the article by the authors as a preprint on arXiv, the statement for the Ramanujan's zeta function that I try to evoke is **Lemma 9.3** from **arXiv:1107.5134**